# SVG marker-mid on specific point on path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I got some code that generates pathes on canvas.
the path objects looks similar to this :

```
<path class="link" d="M450,215.L265,236L225,236" style="stroke-width: 1;"></path>
```

and on view (a,b,c letters are just for explaining the problem):

[image]

My problem is that I want to draw some arrow (marker) on the middle of the line,
between "a" to "b",
but when I create a marker and do a marker-mid attribute, its generates on b point.

I've tried to do some point between a and b, but then marker-mid did the arrows both there and both on b point.

from WEB API documentation :

> The marker-mid defines the arrowhead or polymarker that shall be drawn
>   at every vertex other than the first and last vertex of the given
>    element or basic shape.

How can I disable the marker on point b? 
Or how can I make something like arrow between a-b ? 
Thanks !

Comment: How are you drawing your `path`?  To use `marker-mid` you'd probably have to split your path up.

Answer (score 22):

sometimes its not so easy to split the path at any point you like. Then you can use text on a path with `startOffset` to position an "arrow" at any point on a path...

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 3
}
text {
  font-size: 35px;
  fill: red;
  dominant-baseline: central
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="300px" height="300px">
  <path class="link" id="path1" d="M0 0 L200 400A300 300 0 0 1 490 150"></path>
  <text >
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="10%">➤</textPath>
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="20%">➤</textPath>
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="30%">➤</textPath>
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="40%">➤</textPath>
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="50%">➤</textPath>
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="60%">➤</textPath>
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="70%">➤</textPath>
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="80%">➤</textPath>
    <textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="90%">➤</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks , Its works great ! 
Do you think this is possible to add some circle background behind the textPath ?

Comment: in combination with webfonts everything is possible...
https://cdn.rawgit.com/Holger-Will/misc/master/fonts/test.html

Comment: thats pretty clever

Comment: This saved me from many complex calculations when I was trying to add start and end markers (arrows) to a d3 generated arc.

Comment: Thank you for this clever solution @HolgerWill!  I used this solution to create arrows using D3 in another post.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312716/create-directional-arrows-on-an-svg-path-using-d3/70312717#70312717

Answer (score 4):

> The marker-mid defines the arrowhead or polymarker that shall be drawn at every vertex other than the first and last vertex of the given element or basic shape.

You are drawing a line with vertices `A`, `B`, and `C`, so by definition the marker will be drawn at `B`.

If you want a marker to be drawn between `A` and `B` you will need to draw a `path` from `A` to the midpoint `AB` to `B`.

```html
<svg width="200" height="150">
  <defs>
    <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6" orient="auto">
      <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill: #000;" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <path d='M0,0 L50,50 L100, 100' style='marker-mid:url(#markerArrow); stroke: #000'/>
  <path d='M100,100 L125, 100 L150, 100' style='marker-mid:url(#markerArrow); stroke: #000' />
</svg>
```